# List - Conditional formatting of a "cell" based on another cell in the same row

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have two columns: "LFR sign" and "Filing".

I would like to:

- If the "LFR sign" is not empty -> "Filing " becomes red if it's empty

I am sure this is quite simple for you guys but I am struggling with this since this morning.

Comment: Are you using SP online or 2019? Do you mean that you have to columns: LFR sign and Filing? What is the data type of this columns? Also, can you please explain the conditions in detail? maybe you can attach the screenshot of list view (to see what are the column names and how the data is stored) and expected output you want?

Comment: Hello, yes I'm using SP online. Yes I have two columns, LFR sign and filing, the two columns contain dates. 
I would like to have the Filing column cetto to become red if LFR sign is not empty and Filing column is empty.

Comment: Check my updated answer for JSON code using date fields. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, it works now!

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you want set the color of "Filing" column cell to red if (Correct me if I am wrong):

1. LFR sign column is not empty AND
2. Filing column is empty

Then try adding below JSON to "Filing" column:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if([$LFRSign] != '' && @currentField == '', 'red' , '')"
    },
    "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**Note**: Replace `LFRSign` with the correct **internal name** of your "LFR Sign" column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Reference**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Update from Comments**:

For date fields, try below code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number([$LFRSign]) != 0 && Number(@currentField) == 0, 'sp-field-severity--blocked' , '')"
    },
    "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can find other ways to check if date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)